# Temporarily deny all incoming traffic with firewalld

Tags: centos, security, firewall, firewalld

I'm searching for an equivalent to `ufw default deny` for firewalld; the idea is that after I log in through SSH to my fresh server, I want to block all incoming new connections so that I have time to update and secure the system. I use CentOS7 with firewalld.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from this [serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/q/618164/293440) that limiting traffic at this higher level [requires "rich" rules](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/pipermail/firewalld-users/2013-February/000053.html).

To implement a rich rule that is enacted on the default zone that drops any and all IPv4 traffic:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=$(firewall-cmd --get-default-zone) \
  --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=0.0.0.0/0 drop'
```

This emulates the `ufw default deny` behavior; to instead send an ICMP reject message, change the `drop` to `reject`. The above rule is specific to IPv4; for IPv6, use:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=$(firewall-cmd --get-default-zone) \
  --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv6 source address=::/0 drop'
```

Upon investigation, this adds an entry to iptables that comes *after* the "accept RELATED and ESTABLISHED" connections, so it will not break your existing ssh session. In my testing, the resulting "chain" of iptables goes (for a default zone of 'public'):

```
INPUT -> INPUT_ZONES -> IN_public -> IN_public_deny
```

If you expect to reboot as part of the updates, then add the `--permanent` flag.

If you do not expect to reboot as part of the updates, then you could use the `--timeout` flag, which accepts values such as `5s`, `10m`, or `15h` for "5 seconds", "10 minutes" or "15 hours", respectively. Such a rule will be deleted after that timeout period.

When you want to remove the rule that you've added, simply run same `firewall-cmd` as before, but replacing `--add-rich-rule` with `--remove-rich-rule`; for an IPv4 example:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=$(firewall-cmd --get-default-zone) \
  --remove-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=0.0.0.0/0 accept'
```

Reference: http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html